# Normalization in R 0 to 5

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization, normalize

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
  A       B         C
 ab      gb      0.03
 fn      mn      0.12
 po      er      0.43
 oo      et      0.22
 iu      ew      0.77
 ii      mn      0.14
 dd      wr      0.99
 qw      ty      0.45
```

How do I normalize column C to be from the range of 0-5. I know you can do it like this with dplyr but it doesn't convert it to 0-5.

```
normalize <- function(x){
  return((x-min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x)))
}

scaled_data <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  mutate(NORMALIZED = normalize(C))
```

Comment: You can do with `dplyr` `df1 %>% mutate(C = 5*C/max(C))`

Comment: `scales::rescale()`

Comment: What does "you can do it like this with dplyr but it doesn't convert it to 0-5" mean? You say both that you can and you can't do it like that, so what are you trying to say? Maybe you are trying to say, you know how to use dplyr to do the equivalent of what is as shown, but that doesn't do what you want. But even if you make that clear, why mention that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `dplyr` using `scales::rescale`. I'll leave it to you to add `group_by`.

```
df <-read.table(text="  A       B         C
 ab      gb      0.03
 fn      mn      0.12
 po      er      0.43
 oo      et      0.22
 iu      ew      0.77
 ii      mn      0.14
 dd      wr      0.99
 qw      ty      0.45",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df%>%
mutate(C=scales::rescale(C,to=c(0, 5)))

   A  B        C
1 ab gb 0.000000
2 fn mn 0.468750
3 po er 2.083333
4 oo et 0.989583
5 iu ew 3.854167
6 ii mn 0.572917
7 dd wr 5.000000
8 qw ty 2.187500
```